# Transfer data between client and serviceWorker

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I want to try run websockets in serviceWorker.

**I write code for register serviceWorker:**

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register(
            GetDataForUser.settings.service_worker + "?version=" + GetDataForUser.settings.service_worker_version,
            {scope: './'}
        )
        .then(() => navigator.serviceWorker
            .ready
            .then((worker) => {
        console.log(worker);
                worker.sync.register('syncdata');
            })
        )
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', event => {
        console.log('++++++++++++++++++++', event.data.msg, event.data.url);
    });
}
```

**And write serviceWorker code:**

```
var ws = null;

self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
    console.log('Install');
});

self.addEventListener('activate', (event) => {
    console.log('Activate');

    ws = new WebSocket('ws://local.ll:8880');

    ws.onopen = function() {
        console.log("Open");
    };

    // On message receive
    ws.onmessage = function (event) {
        console.log("Message receive " + event.data);
        console.log(event);
        event.ports[0].postMessage({'test': 'This is my response.'});
    };

    // On error connection
    ws.onerror = function (error) {
        console.log("Error " + error.message);
    };

    // On close connection
    ws.onclose = function (event) {
        if (event.wasClean) {
            console.log('clean closed');

        } else {
            console.log('broken connection');
        }
        console.log('Code: ' + event.code + ' reason: ' + event.reason);
    };
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {});

self.addEventListener('message', function (evt) {
    console.log('postMessage received', evt.data);
    ws.send('121212');
});
```

**I try to send data to serviceWorker next:**

```
navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage({'hello': 'world'});
```

**But receive an error:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'postMessage' of null

console.log(navigator.serviceWorker);
ServiceWorkerContainer {controller: null, ready: Promise, oncontrollerchange: null, onmessage: null}
```

**Trying to send message from serviceWorker to client next:**

```
event.ports[0].postMessage({'test': 'This is my response.'});
```

But event.ports is empty.

**Whats wrong?
How to transfer data between client and serviceWorker.**

Answer (score 3):

To fix your error of controller being null, you need to add the activate event listener

```
self.clients.claim()
```

Without that, when the service worker is activated, the page is not controlled by it until the next navigation. This allows the service worker to take control of the pages as soon as it's active.

But I don't think it's your only problem. Looking at your code I think you're confusing WebSocket and MessageChannel. You seem to try to use WebSocket to send messages between client and service worker where you should be using MessageChannel for that.

For exemple if we want to send messages from the client to the SW and allow the SW to respond to those messages, we create a MessageChannel, and we send a port of this channel allong with the message for the SW to use in his response.
in the client :

```
var msg = new MessageChannel();
msg.port1.onmessage = function(event){
    //Response received from SW
    console.log(event.data);
};
// Send message to SW
navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage("hello", [msg_chan.port2]);
```

in the SW :

```
self.addEventListener('message', function(event){
    //Message received from client
    console.log(event.data);
    //Send response to client using the port that was sent with the message
    event.ports[0].postMessage("world");
});
```

Comment: Trying this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerContainer/controller#Example and receive "This page is not currently controlled by a service worker."

Comment: Adding self.clients.claim() and it is not help

Comment: >> You seem to try to use WebSocket to send messages between client and service worker.    I try to use WebSocket for massage between serviceWorker and server backend.

Comment: Try with event.waitUntil(self.clients.claim());

Comment: Why are you using websocket inside a service worker? I'm asking because I don't think it can work and I'm trying to see if there's another solution to achieve what you want

Comment: I need receive data from backend online, so ajax will be to hard for server so I need WebSocket. If I will create WebSocket in each page - it is to bad, because sockets are limited. So I need share socket between pages. I create this functionality with sharedWorker, now try create it with serviceWorker because it can work even if page was closed. =)

Comment: >> Try with event.waitUntil Trying but it not works until i refresh page.

Comment: If you dont want to wait for page refresh you need to add this in your install listener `event.waitUntil(self.skipWaiting());` However, what you are trying to do won't work. Service workers don't run in the background, they terminate as soon as their promise is resolved. The only way to push data to a service worker when the page is closed is using the Push API

Comment: Start check worker state, and when it change to activated - run message like you say and it works, thanks! Code example: https://github.com/Shkarbatov/WebSocketInServiceWorkerJS

Answer (score 0):

**Correct and worked example, only for understanding, not for production:**
https://github.com/Shkarbatov/WebSocketInServiceWorkerJS